# Updating component display from route

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

To learn more about using services and components, I'm trying to set up a simple flash-message style service. Within my route, I'm saving a record and receiving either a json notice or json error from the server.

Since this is a behavior I'd eventually like to use app-wide, I'm using a simple service (injected into my routes) to handle displaying the message. Within a route, I'm able to call `this.get('notification').displayMessage(msg)`.

Currently the `displayMessage` function within the service is just alerting the message because I'm stuck on how to create a component that the service can "update". How can a service communicate with a component so that I can send a message and display it from the component template?

**profile/index route**

```
user.save().then( (response) => {
  //display response.notice in the app-notification component template
}, (response) => {
  let errors = JSON.parse(response.errors);
  //display response.error in the app-notification component template
  this.get('notification').displayMessage(errors[0]);
}
```

**service**

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const { Service } = Ember;

export default Service.extend({

  displayMessage(msg) {
    alert("message ---> " + msg);
  }
});
```

**component**

```
???
```

**component template**

```
<h2 class="alert">{{message}}</h2>
```

**application template**

```
{{app-notification message=message}}
```

Answer (score 0):

In terms of accessing the service, I like the example that they using the docs: http://guides.emberjs.com/v2.1.0/applications/services/

The ShoppingCart service is injected into components that need to access the Cart.

Once you have access to the ShoppingCart you should be able to:

- set a Notification in the service for User from your route error catch.
- set up a Computed Property based on the Notification service (some sort of hasNotification method) on the Component `hasError` that can toggle the error message.

As soon as you set a notification your component will see that the property it is watching has changed and will show/hide your notification.